# Correct terminology for a repeating radio transmission

Tags: uhf, jargon

I am using 'active radio tags' in a particle tracking experiment. The tags emit a 433 MHz signal containing a unique ID code at a programmable time interval and I am attempting to locate them by surveying a zone with a passive antenna and a GPS.

Is it correct to refer to individual transmission instances (i.e a very short signal containing one 'radio frame' with a defined beginning and end) as a 'transmission'? Is there a more accurate term? Ideally the term would be as brief as possible.

How would you refer to the 'transmission interval' i.e the delay between successive 'transmissions'? I have seen this referred to as a 'signal impulse'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, a "transmission" is pretty much what I'd call this. You could also call it a *radio packet* if the data you're transmitting is actually packetized – i.e. data with fixed structure within each transmission and the data then being handled based on that information.

I would not call them "signal impulse". They are not impulses, and adding "signal" to it makes the reader expect them to be impulses in the signal-theoretical sense.

In your specific application, these could be called *beacon packets* (compare Bluetooth LE beacons); you could call your time period *beacon interval* (a term also used in WLAN for the interval between beacon packets that access points regularly send to announce their presence).

So, *transmission* and *transmission interval* sound good. Depending on how much you want your application to bleed into your naming, you can find other terms – often drawing from analogies to existing technologies.

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast and detailed reply! I will continue with the more generic terms 'transmission' and 'transmission interval', also using 'radio packet' when outlining the equipment I use in detail.